# pandas dataframe for search works too slow,why?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, dataframe

I used python pandas for my project,but i found it's too slow when i do this:
`df1.loc[id,'a']=df2.loc[id,'a']`.And df1 is got from `read_table` function,df2 is got from groupby function.
Then,i tried something else,i run like this:
`df1.loc[id,'a']=2`  ,  it's still very slow
But when i try this：
`df2.loc[id,'a']=2`  , it's very fast,almost 300 times faster.
df2 works much faster than df1.
I dont know why.what's the difference between a normal df and a df from groupby
? is it because the index?can anybody help me ?

Comment: You'll need to post raw data and code that demonstrates this as it's impossible for anyone to give you an accurate answer as it stands

Comment: Have you tried using groupby on `df1` and then executing the command `df1.loc[id,'a']=2`?